# Is it OK to force the user to start a subscription + trial?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store, subscriptions

By Apple's rules, is it considered OK to force a subscription + trial when the user first uses an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is ok. Your mileage may vary with the particular reviewer you get but in general Apple is very liberal with what content you choose to put behind a paywall. After all, you could charge users to even install your app if it were a paid application.

Apple does list some additional do's and don't's on the IAP section  of the [app review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase). These are worth reading over, especially if you are considering using renewable subscriptions.